# PyQt5 listWidget refuse to get smaller in QtDesigner

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a layout in designer that looks like this:

[image]

except that I want the listWidget to be as small as possible, and only expand vertically based on the minimum height needed to hold all it's items. However for some reason it refuses to cooperate, and just remains at it's default size. I tried to do multiple things to change it:

1. setting the stretch factor of textLabel to listWidget to be 1,0
2. setting the sizePolicy of the listWidget as well as the widget it is in to be minimum
3. setting the resizeMode of the listWidget to be adjust
4. setting the sizePolicy of the button (I want it to fill up all the remaining space) to expanding
5. setting the stretch factor of the widget to the button to 0,1

but none of these work. In addition, the window does not seem to be able to become smaller than this despite there being no minimum size set for anything, leading me to believe that there is an invisible minimum size for the listWidget that is not related to the minimum size shown in the properties. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Edit: after taking a suggestion of using preferred size policy and an expanding button, it still does not want to work. Here's the ui file for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>318</width>
    <height>277</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2" stretch="0,0">
   <property name="spacing">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="leftMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="topMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="rightMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="bottomMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <item>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
     <property name="sizePolicy">
      <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Maximum">
       <horstretch>0</horstretch>
       <verstretch>0</verstretch>
      </sizepolicy>
     </property>
     <property name="baseSize">
      <size>
       <width>0</width>
       <height>0</height>
      </size>
     </property>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout" stretch="0,0">
      <property name="spacing">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeConstraint">
       <enum>QLayout::SetDefaultConstraint</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="leftMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="topMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="rightMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="bottomMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <item>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Maximum">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>TextLabel</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QListWidget" name="listWidget">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Maximum">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeAdjustPolicy">
         <enum>QAbstractScrollArea::AdjustToContents</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="resizeMode">
         <enum>QListView::Fixed</enum>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
     <property name="sizePolicy">
      <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Minimum">
       <horstretch>0</horstretch>
       <verstretch>0</verstretch>
      </sizepolicy>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>PushButton</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the stretch factors to default and then

1. set `QListWidget` set vertical size policy to `Preferred`
2. set the `QPushButton` vertical size policy to `Expanding`
3. set the `QLabel` vertical size policy to `Maximum`
4. Set the sizeAdjuctPolicy for `QListWidget` to `AdjustToContents`

The size policies in qt are not what they seem upon first glance. `Minimum` actually means grow as much as you can. `Maximum` actually means shrink as much as you can.  you can learn more about them in the [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsizepolicy.html)

The last part you can do is overwrite the QListWidget.sizeHint method to dynamically adjust to the number of items in the list.

Here is a runnable example:

```
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *

class ListWidget(QListWidget):

    def sizeHint(self):
        size = super().sizeHint()
        frame = self.frameWidth() * 2
        items_height = self.count() * self.sizeHintForRow(0)
        height = min(super().maximumHeight(), items_height)
        size.setHeight(height + frame)
        return size

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        return self.sizeHint()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.resize(318, 277)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy1 = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy2 = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.label = QLabel('Label', self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget = ListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton = QPushButton('Push Button', self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.listWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.listWidget.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy1)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.additem)

    def additem(self):
        i = self.listWidget.count()
        self.listWidget.addItem(QListWidgetItem("Item" + str(i), type=0))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: That does not seem to work for some reason, the behaviour of the listWidget did not change. I also tried to use `Maximum` but it still was stuck at that size. I included the ui code I was testing in my post for reference.

Comment: @Alexander that will not suffice, as abstract scroll areas have a default minimum size hint which is based on various aspects (font, style, etc). A maximum height must be specified, and that should probably be dynamic, since the OP asks for "expand vertically based on the minimum height needed to hold all it's items".

Comment: @musicamante  I know... I am still trying to figure it out

Comment: @ChronoVortex  Please see updated answer.

Comment: @Alexander That's better, but still not enough, you'll also need to: 1. override `minimumSizeHint()` and `return self.sizeHint()` (or the other way around); 2. provide a minimum height for no items (possibly, use `self.itemDelegate().sizeHint(self.viewOptions(), QModelIndex()).height()`) 3. compute the height considering a *maximum* (arbitrary) amount, otherwise the widget would become too tall if there are too many items; 4. always add the double of the  [`frameWidth()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html#frameWidth-prop) so that no vertical scroll bar is shown unnecessarily.

Comment: Not sure if I'm thinking along the right lines, but if code has to be used then do I not just take the total height of all the widgets and set that as the maximum size of the listWidget? I noticed that the listWidget can be come smaller if I manually update the maximum size everything a widget is added/updated, but I want to see if there's a better alternative.

Comment: @ChronoVortex That is essentially what I am doing, doing it this way is simply more universal and won't be thrown off by changing the font or font size or making any other style adjustments, or if your items are not all a uniform size.